# Android restore activity stack from notification exactly like the history selection does

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have an application in which I keep all my activities with launchMode="singleTask". I like this better that doing flags soup ( mixing combinations to obtain the desired effect ), and base on receiving onNewIntent calls.

However I have the following problem.

If I launch the application, then R activity is started ( has launcher, Roster activity ).

Then I launch activity S.

(1) If I press the home button and I put the application to background, and then I press the history button ( the button from the rightest on Nexus 4, I think it's called like this ) I will be shown the S activity in the same state I left it after I pressed the home button.

(2) However, If I press the home button and I put the application to background,and then I click on a notification to launch my application, then R activity is launched and the onNewIntent is called for it.

Basically I would like the same behavior in the second case also. I am launching the application like this when clicking the notification:

```
   Intent rosterIntent = new Intent(this, RosterActivity.class);
   rosterIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
   rosterIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 2,
   rosterIntent, 0);
```

It would seem this would be enough to relaunch the application in the same state I left it in, but it doesn't work. Maybe it's related that I have all my activities singleTask...

Can someone tell me, please, If I need to add more flags to my intent, or the pending intent to obtain what I want?

Regards,

NOTE: it seems that clicking the launcher icon after the application is in the background has the same behavior like (2), so just selecting from history (1) is the behaviour that I want.

Comment: post your manifest. In general, using special launch modes is a really bad idea. Once I see your manifest I can tell you more.

Answer (score 0):

i use **NotificationCompat** from support library. I think you need add these flags:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

and for builder:

```
builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Should works.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `android:launchMode="singleTop` to your activity declaration tag, in your AndoridManifest.xml.

```
 <activity
        android:name="co.ramansoft.lyricsplayer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```